# Swift Combine - Merging multiple Futures

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I'm trying to merge multiple Futures with combine and I'm out of luck so far. I'm trying using Publishers.MergeMany similar to this.

```
let f = Future<Void, Error> { promise in
   promise(.success(Void()))
}

let g = Future<Void, Error> { promise in
  promise(.success(Void()))
}

var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

Publishers.MergeMany([f,g]).collect()
.sink { _ in
    print("merge")
} receiveValue: { value in
    print("done")
}.store(in: &subscriptions)
```

For some reason on my real case scenario, only the first publisher finish but the other one get stuck in oblivion.

If a call each Future one by one sequentially, all works fine.

Does anybody had an issue like this before?

Comment: What happens if instead of calling `promise(.success(())` immediately you wait for like a second? And what happens if you don't use `collect()`?

Comment: If I don't use `collect` it finish without completing all Futures. What do you mean by waiting a second? Is this a bug on `Publishers.MergeMany` API?

Comment: I get the impression that the Future might be finishing before `MergeMany` can catch it. I would try to wrap the `promise(...)` in a `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter...` to make sure it's executed after `MergeMany` is created.

Comment: It's a problem that the code in the question doesn't actually reproduces your issue. You need to provide a reproducible example to help with debugging. As posted, it works.

Comment: the thing about Future is that it won't wait for any subscriber to publish, as soon as it created it will execute and “ The future does not re-execute its promise; instead, it shares or replays its output”.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "only the first publisher finish but the other one get stuck in oblivion"? I tried this code snippet and the output is `done` followed by `merge` which is the expected behavior. Do you see something else happening?